# Alterar o Delimitador do arquivo CSV em Python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, csv

Eu estou com uma dificuldade no delimitador das células do arquivo CSV, quando mando o comando de salvar o arquivo editado em *CSV* `escritor.writerow([linhas])` o delimitador por padrão é a `,`, mais eu preciso alterar para `;` pois quando eu abro o arquivo no *Excel*, ele não reconhece a quebra das células com `,`, então fica tudo em uma coluna só.
Meu codigo esta assim:

```
import csv

coluna_Heading = 0
coluna_Number = 1

with open("testeIfHeading00.csv", "r") as arquivo_lido, open("saida.csv", "w", newline= "") as arquivo_criado:

    #def o leitor CSV do arquivo
    leitor = csv.reader(arquivo_lido, delimiter=';')

    #def o escritor CSV do arquivo
    escritor = csv.writer(arquivo_criado, delimiter=';')

    #percorre as linhas do arquivo a ser lido
    separatec = " "
    for linhas in leitor:
        if (len(linhas[coluna_Number]) == 1) or len(linhas[coluna_Number]) <= 2:
            separatec = linhas[coluna_Heading]
        linhas.append(separatec)

        print(linhas)
        escritor.writerow([linhas])
```

Comment: Falta colocar um trecho do código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver a minha duvida. O python exportava os arquivos sem o delimitador que eu queria pois mandava exportar como um vetor entre *[ ]* no código acima exportava com o delimitador *,* e não com *;* ou seja somente tirei a *[ ]* do parametro

```
escritor.writerow(linhas)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use o parâmetro "delimiter", por exemplo:

```
import csv
# ...
with open('arquivo.csv', 'wb') as arquivo:
    arquivo_csv = csv.writer(arquivo, delimiter=';')
    arquivo_csv.writerow( ... )
# ...
```